# Is this possible to develop some criteria based search on the Strings in C# or JAVA?

Tags: java, string, c#-4.0, replace

I have one List in C#.This String array contains elements of Paragraph that are read from the Ms-Word File.for example,

list 0-> The picture above shows the main report which will be used for many of the markup samples in this chapter. There are several interesting elements in this sample document. First there  rae the basic text elements, the primary building blocks for your document. Next up is the table at the bottom of the report which will be discussed in full, including the handy styling effects such as row-banding. Finally the image displayed in the header will be added to finalize the report.

list 1->The picture above shows the main report which will be used for many of the markup samples in this chapter. There are several interesting elements in this sample document. First there  rae the basic text elements, the primary building blocks for your document. Various other elements of WordprocessingML will also be handled. By moving the formatting information into styles a higher degree of re-use is made possible. The document will be marked using custom XML tags and the insertion of other advanced elements such as a table of contents is discussed. But before all the advanced features can be added, the base of the document needs to be built.

Some thing like that.

Now My search String is :

The picture above shows the main report which will be used for many of the markup samples in this chapter. There are several interesting elements in this sample document. First there  rae the basic text elements, the primary building blocks for your document. Next up is the table at the bottom of the report which will be discussed in full, including the handy styling effects such as row-banding. Before going over all the elements which make up the sample documents a basic document structure needs to be laid out. When you take a WordprocessingML document and use the Windows Explorer shell to rename the docx extension to zip you will find many different elements, especially in larger documents.

I want to check my search String with that list elements.

my criteria is "If each list element contains 85% match or exact match of search string then we want to retrieve that list elements.

In our case,

list 0 -> more satisfies my search string.
list 1 -it also matches some text,but i think below not equal to my criteria...

How i do this kind of criteria based search on String...?

I have more confusion on my problem also

Welcome your ideas and  thoughts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is ***DISTANCE*** or ***"string distance"***.  and also, "***Paragraph similarity***" 
You seek to implement a function which would express as a scalar, say a percentage as suggested in the question, indicative of how *similar* a string is from another string.

Plain string distance functions such as [**hamming**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) or [**Levenstein**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) may not be appropriate, for they work at character level rather than at word level, but generally these algorithms convey the idea of what is needed.

Working at word level you'll probably also want to take into account some common NLP features, for example ignore (or give less weight to) very common words (such as '*the*', '*in*', '*of*' etc.) and maybe allow for some forms of stemming.   The order of the words, or for the least their proximity may also be of import.

One key factor to remember is that even with relatively short strings, many distances functions can be quite expensive, computationally speaking.  Before selecting one particular algorithm you'll need to get an idea of the general parameters of the problem:

- how many strings would have to be compared?  (on average, maximum)
- how many words/token do the string contain?  (on average, max)
- Is it possible to introduce a simple (quick) filter to reduce the number of strings to be compared ?
- how fancy do we need to get with  linguistic features ?
- is it possible to pre-process the strings ?
- Are all the records in a single language ?

[*Comparing Methods for Single Paragraph Similarity Analysis*](http://mall.psy.ohio-state.edu/wiki/images/e/e7/StonesDennisKwantes09.pdf), a scholarly paper provides a survey of relevant techniques and considerations.

In a nutshell, the the amount of design-time and run-time one can apply this relatively open problem varies greatly and is typically a compromise between the level of precision desired vs. the run-time resources and the overall complexity of the solution which may be acceptable.
In its simplest form, when the order of the words matters little, computing the sum of factors based on the [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf) values of the words which match may be a very acceptable solution.
Fancier solutions may introduce a pipeline of processes borrowed from NLP, for example [Part-of-Speech Tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part-of-speech_tagging) (say for the purpose of avoiding false positive such as "*SAW*" as a noun (to cut wood), and "*SAW*" as the past tense of the verb "to see". or more likely to filter outright some of the words based on their grammatical function), stemming and possibly semantic substitutions, concept extraction or [latent semantic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) for Java or [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) for c#. I don't think it'll do the percentage requirement you want out of the box, but it's a great tool for doing text matching.

You maybe could run a separate query for each word, and then work out the percentage yourself of ones that matched.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an idea (and not a solution by any means but something to get started with)

```
private IEnumerable<string> SearchList = GetAllItems(); // load your list

    void Search(string searchPara)
    {
        char[] delimiters = new char[]{' ','.',','};
        var wordsInSearchPara = searchPara.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(a=>a.ToLower()).OrderBy(a => a);

        foreach (var item in SearchList)
        {
            var wordsInItem = item.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(a => a.ToLower()).OrderBy(a => a);
            var common = wordsInItem.Intersect(wordsInSearchPara);

           // now that you know the common items, you can get the differential 

        }

    }
```